# Writing a Unit Test for a Servlet

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am writing a Unit Test for Java Servlet:

```
    @Reference
    private transient SearchService searchService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(@Nonnull SlingHttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        final JsonResponse jsonResponse = new JsonResponse(response);
        final String title = request.getParameter("title");
        final List<APIResult> locations = LocationFinderUtil.getLocationResultStream(request, searchService)
                .filter(result -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(title) &&
                        (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(result.getTitle(), title) || StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(result.getAdditionalAddress(), title)))
                .map(result -> create(result, title))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        jsonResponse.write(locations);
    }
```

My test code is:

```
    private final AemContext context =  new AemContext(ResourceResolverType.RESOURCERESOLVER_MOCK);

    SearchService searchService;

    ResourceResolverService resourceResolverService;

    GeocodingService geocodingService;


    @InjectMocks
    private LocationFinderByTitleService underTest = new LocationFinderByTitleService();

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        context.load().json("/component/content/location/content.json", "/content/de");
        resourceResolverService = Mockito.mock(ResourceResolverService.class);
        geocodingService = Mockito.mock(GeocodingService.class);
        searchService = Mockito.mock(SearchService.class);


        Map<String, Object> pm = new HashMap<>();
        pm.put("title", "Shop");
        context.request().setMethod("GET");
        context.request().setParameterMap(pm);
    }


    @Test
    void doGetTest() throws IOException {
        MockSlingHttpServletRequest request = context.request();
        MockSlingHttpServletResponse response = context.response();
        

        underTest.doGet(request, response);
```

The problem is that my `underTest.doGet(request, response)` fails while the searchService is null.
The SearchService has to @Reference annotations itself and two public methods:

```
    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverService resourceResolverService;

    @Reference
    private GeocodingService geocodingService;

    private final Map<String, List<LocationResult>> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public List<LocationResult> getResults(@Nonnull GoogleMapsApiConfigurationModel configModel, @Nonnull String pagePath, @Nullable String zipCity) {...}
        

    public void cacheLocations(Resource resource) {...}
```

My question is how to I correctly Mock the SearchService in my Unit Test class?

Comment: Did you mean "fails *because* the `searchService ` is `null`? Don't mix @InjectMocks and mocking in @BeforeEach. Use a @Mock annotation on the objects you want to inject into `LocationFinderByTitleService`, and don't create `LocationFinderByTitleService` -- @InjectMocks will do that for you. Find some examples of Mockito annotations being used and follow them.

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies